# How can I call a PHP function from another server?

Tags: php

Is there a way that I can call a PHP function from another server?

I have access to both these 2 servers. I want to call a PHP function from server 1 and use it in server 2.

What do I need to change on both servers to make it possible? Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what the function does. You perhaps can return an json string with whatever the function does?

Comment: I actually want to do this to secure my code.

Comment: You can do it by making function APIs and pass values and in return, you will get the desired output.

Comment: This is basically what an API can do. You call an URL from your other server with either get or post variables, and you listen for an output (with a json array) to look for a return.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an API to do this. On **Server 1** using Curl or GuzzleHttp you want to make an API call to **Server 2**

When **Server 2** receives the request from **Server 1** you can have the function run.

One thing to consider here is security, you will need a way of verifying that only **Server 1** is making requests and not somebody who's figured out your API. Usually an API Key is passed when making the request and it's checked on the API.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially what you're asking is how to do a [remote procedure call (RPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) between two PHP applications. To communicate between two applications (PHP applications in your case) that are hosted on different servers you need to choose some kind of [communication protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol).

The protocol you choose would depend on many things, including what your applications do, how often they would communicate, what kind of data you want to send between them, etc.

I'm no expert myself, but from what I know [gRPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRPC) and [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) are two of the more popular API communication protocols. See [these](https://www.bizety.com/2019/04/11/api-battles-grpc-vs-rest/) [articles](https://medium.com/@EdgePress/is-grpc-the-future-of-client-server-communication-b112acf9f365) for comparisons between the two. If your servers are going to be communicating back and forth very frequently you might want to consider [WebSockets or MQTT](https://systembash.com/mqtt-vs-websockets-vs-http2-the-best-iot-messaging-protocol/).

For most of these protocols you're going to have to set up a service/server on the one server (the server on which your function is that you want to be called) and a client on the other (the server from which you want to call the function).

To set up gRPC, have a look at this PHP [tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/php/).

To set up REST, you would need to expose a HTTP endpoint on your server-host and consume the endpoint from your client-host. Exposing the endpoint is most easily done with an API framework of which there are many (just Google "PHP REST framework"). Consuming the endpoint can be done with a HTTP client, such as [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/), like some of the other answers mention.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry this is not possible like sesssion if not same server session will not take effect on other pages.

Comment: Can you explain that further? The OP has not mentioned anything about sessions